# SSD upgrade for iMac 2007 - criteria

Tags: hard-drive, imac, ssd, upgrade, bootable-disk

I'm looking to upgrade my slow 2007 iMac with a new 1TB SSD and looking for recommendations on what parameters to look - that is, which SSDs are compatible with my older iMac, and which are best? It seems fairly easy to install, I just want to be armed with the criteria to choose the right SSD.

Here are the specs:
https://support.apple.com/kb/SP16?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

I see a lot of them are 2.5", I believe the HDD in it now is a 3.5", does that mean I need the adapter bracket in order to install?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because recommendation questions are not suitable for this site. You may want to post your question on Hardward Recommendations (hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com). See apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for details.

Comment: Edited to remove "product recommendation" aspects.  I would love to see this answered.